# How to synchronize multiple threading operation in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios4

Why do we use synchronize multiple threading operation & when can we use @synchronize
while using threading operation.

this might be a stupid question, i need to understand the concept of threading. Please help in understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html). Your question is very broad.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we use synchronize multiple threading operation

Consider `@synchronize` as a recursive lock for the argument (instance) you pass to it. It's helpful when you want to lock without adopting to `NSLocking` or declaring an ivar.

`@synchronize` is not an ideal solution where speed matters. `pthread_mutex`es are several times faster, last I tested.

> ...when can we use @synchronize while using threading operation.

It functions like a recursive mutex. Therefore, it is safe* to introduce this at any point in your program's flow. It is also safe to request multiple locks (via `@synchronize`) for an object; it is recursive, it will not deadlock if you acquire a lock on its argument twice from the same thread.

**as safe as recursive mutex, but `@synchronized` will also unlock if an exception is thrown.*

---

If you simply need to know why locking is important in simple terms: locking is required to prevent multiple reads or writes to objects and/or memory at the same time. Without locking, reading and writing from multiple threads at the same time can blow away your program's integrity because unprotected reads and writes may occur at any point in your programs execution (which will result in undefined behavior, invalid states, partial updates when read, inconsistent states, and a good source for crashes that are hard to isolate). There are some pretty big reads on this topic, but locking and threading at the lower level is what you want to focus on (not topics specific to `@synchronize`).